# Trouble Avoiding Correlated Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to avoid a correlated subquery in my SQL, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Here's my current PostgreSQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO book_collection (publisher, p_key, collection_name, page_number) 
(SELECT publisher,
        p_key, 
        source, 
        pages 
 FROM db_publication_new AS d 
 WHERE d.type =
'book_collection' 
 AND (SELECT type 
      FROM db_publication_new 
      WHERE dblp_key = d.crossref) 
  = 'book');
```

So basically I have a table called `db_publication_new`, and it contains publications that are of various types, two of which are called `book_collection` and `book`. Every `publication`, regardless of type, has a column called `crossref` in it that contains a `p_key`. This `p_key` itself refers to another `publication` inside this same database.

I want to get all of the `book_collection` publications inside of this table that have a `crossref` of type `book`. How do I do this efficiently?

I've only been able write the inefficient statement above, and due to the amount of records in my table it is taking too long to complete. How can I make the statement not contain a correlated subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO book_collection (publisher, p_key, collection_name, page_number) 
VALUES
(SELECT d1.publisher,
    d1.p_key, 
    d1.source, 
    d1.pages 
FROM db_publication_new AS d1, db_publication_new AS d2 
WHERE d1.type = 'book_collection' 
AND d2.dblp_key = d1.crossref 
AND d2.type = 'book');
```

Comment: Much better. Finished in about 2 or 3 seconds, while before I gave up after 10 minutes.